# Having issue with front Realtek HD Audio 2nd output

Tags: audio, drivers

I just built a new computer and audio sounds muffled and distorted. I installed and reinstalled all the latest drivers for Realtek but this issue persists. My motherboard is AORUS Z#90 pro wifi. I have my headphones in the front panel of my tower and my output device is Realtek HD audio 2nd output. I should note that other audio outputs work fine but its just this one that is causing issues. Also when i test audio, i can hear the test noises just fine but then when i play anything else I get distorted noises. No damage was done to the tower itself.

Can anyone provide any advice?

Comment: You used to be able to check & switch in the BIOS whether the front panel would use HD Audio or AC97… might be worth a look to see if that's still switchable. [I've no idea how you get to it on a modern machine]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding using front panel audio. I'm guessing that your cable is not well isolated and it is collecting all distortion like antenna.
Buy the audio jack extension cable and use back panel output.

Comment: That's interesting, because they are good quality headphones. Also it isn't a small static distortion, more a distortion that renders anything you are listening to terrible buggy quality.